# C# RenderTargetBitmap to SoftwareBitmap

Tags: c#, uwp

How do I get a RenderTargetBitmap object into a SoftwareBitmap? It is possible to get a RenderTargetBitmap as Image Source and on the other side i can use a SoftwareBitmap as a SoftwareBitmapSource and turn that into an ImageSource. But how can I convert RenderTargetBitmap directly to SoftwareBitmap?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RenderTargetBitmap.[GetPixelsAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.getpixelsasync.aspx) returns an IBuffer which you can copy into a SoftwareBitmap with SoftwareBitmap.[CreateCopyFromBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn887372.aspx)

Comment: How can I covert it to a CanvasBitmap later? I am using  CanvasBitmap.CreateFromSoftwareBitmap but i get System.Exception: The bitmap pixel format is unsupported.